# Transistor operating region

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt

[image]

How to decide the operating region of given transistor as shown in the figure?
I mean is it possible to decide the operating region of bjt without knowing the Load(Assuming pure resistor and supply voltage of opamp +15 and -15) value.

Comment: Are you looking for detailed calculations that derive from Ebers-Moll? Or just an approach as shown in Andy's answer? (Which is good, so far as it goes.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Because of positive feedback the op-amp output will run hard against the positive rail and apply a high-level voltage to the base. This voltage cannot be determined from the circuit because power rails are not shown and the op-amp is only stated to be "ideal". If ideal means it can produce an infinite voltage on its output then that is what will be produced.

I suspect that the question is faulty and the inverting and non-inverting terminals are incorrectly shown with the intention being that this circuit is a VCCS (voltage-controlled-current-source).

If that is the case then the voltage at the collector would be 2 volts and the current through the 10.5 kohm would be 3 volts / 10,500 = 286 uA.

That current would flow through the load plus ~5% extra due to the base current and beta only being 20.

If the load resistance is too high to draw this current then this clearly is a situation where the idea behind the "intended" circuit has a limitation as with any form of voltage-controlled-current-source.

In this particular circuit and assuming the BJT is operating close to saturation (Vce = 0.2 volts), the maximum resistance of the load will be limited to about 1.8 volts / 286 uA = 6293 ohms.

Comment: I can show a thread of thinking, using Ebers-Moll, that can refine on this. In the limit as the model's active mode \$\beta\to\infty\$, or is sufficiently larger than the specified value anyway, then \$V_\text{CE}\to V_T\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\beta_F=20\right)\$, or about \$77.5\:\text{mV}\$. This is independent of saturation current but does assume things like the emission coefficient is 1, etc. So I'd say the load is \$\approx 6730\:\Omega\$.

Comment: @jonk. I was basing the 200 mV drop on experience of constant current circuits like the above and the point at which their accuracy begins to fall. I expect I could have said 100 mV and be about 99% right!

Comment: I just enjoy equations and models a lot. It's fun to see what predictions they make or how they dissolve when taken in some direction. This question was kind of fun because I learned a new result from playing "mathematician" for a moment. :)

Comment: @jonk you ARE a very good maths guy.